# Django: how to access queryset instance inside layout of FormHelper

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I am using a formset to update a list of ingredient properties.

```
IngredientFormSet = modelformset_factory(Ingredient, form=IngredientForm, extra=0)

formset = IngredientFormSet(queryset=ingredients_dictinct)
# I am passing a list of ingredients as queryset

helper = RecipeIngredientFormSetHelper()
```

My form helper code is:

```
class RecipeIngredientFormSetHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RecipeIngredientFormSetHelper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_method = 'post'
        self.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div(HTML("{{ forloop.counter }}"),
                    css_class='col-xs-2', style='text-align:center'),
                Div('name', css_class='col-xs-2',),
                Div('munit', css_class='col-xs-2',),
                Div('rate', css_class='col-xs-2',),
                Div('typeofingredient', css_class='col-xs-2',),
                Div('density_kg_per_lt', css_class='col-xs-2',),
                Div('density_pcs_per_kg', css_class='col-xs-1',),
                Div('density_pcs_per_lt', css_class='col-xs-1',),
                css_class='row',style="border-top:1px solid;padding-top:20px")
            )
        self.add_input(Submit("submit", "Save"))
        self.render_required_fields = True
```

In the self.layout using HTML(), how to show some properties of the ingredient object

How to access the ingredient passed in the queryset inside the Layout

Eg:

```
self.layout = Layout(
                Div(
                    Div(HTML("{{ forloop.counter }}"),
                        HTML("{{ ingredient.somemodelmethod }}"),
                        css_class='col-xs-2', style='text-align:center'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I grappled with the same issue. The solution I implemented was to create a field which renders its value as plain text.

1. Add a plain_text form field to the model form
2. Implement a custom widget to render the text input as plain text
3. Set the plain_text field value within the form init
4. Use the plain_text Field in the FormHelper instead of HTML

   ```
   from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
   class PlainTextWidget(forms.Widget):
       def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
           return mark_safe(value) if value is not None else '-'

   class IngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):
       plain_text = forms.CharField(widget=PlainTextWidget,required=False)
       ....

       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(IngredientForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.initial['plain_text'] = self.instance.somemodelmethod()


   self.layout = Layout(
       Div(
           Div(
               HTML("{{ forloop.counter }}"),
               Field('plain_text'),
   ```

Comment: It was long time i did this. I will check the solution

Comment: render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'